# Feature Type Unknown exception in GeoServer WFS request

Tags: geoserver, wfs, geonode

I recently upgraded GeoServer from 2.12 to 2.142 because of a GeoNode update. A WFS GetFeature link failed in the new version of GeoServer:

```
http://myhost/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=geonode:fr_admin1&outputformat=SHAPE-ZIP
```

The error message I got was something like:

```
<ows:Exception exceptionCode="InvalidParameterValue" locator="typeName">
    ows:ExceptionText>Feature type geonode:fr_admin1 unknown</ows:ExceptionText>
```

There is an exception "Feature type unknown" returned. However, I never had this issue in GeoServer ver. 2.12. Is there any changes for the WFS GetFeature request in GeoServer ver. 2.14? How to solve this problem?

Comment: Version 2.0.0 uses typeNames not typeName

Comment: @IanTurton Thanks for the response. I changed the url into "http://myhost/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=geonode:fr_admin1&outputformat=SHAPE-ZIP", but the issue persists.

Comment: `service=wfs` should be `service=WFS`

Answer (score 1):

Both `typeName` and `typeNames` work fine on a local machine for me.

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typenames=topp%3Atasmania_cities
```

and

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typename=topp%3Atasmania_cities
```

Things to check:

1. Make sure that you really have a layer `geonode:fr_admin1` and it is enabled.
2. Test with a standard data layer (like `topp:tasmania_cities`).
3. look in the log file to see if there is an error message.
4. Turn logging level up to `GEOSERVER_DEVELOPER` and check again.